# How to solve unhandeled promise rejections?

Tags: json, reactjs, express, rest

error :  `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`
I m making a **MERN** stack app, In **Frontend** I have signup form and below given is POST method of it.

```
const onSignUp = async (e) => {            
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const body = {
                username,  
                email, 
                password, 
                firstname, 
                lastname, 
                country_code, 
                phone_no,  
                address, 
                city, 
                state, 
                country
            };
            console.log(typeof(JSON.stringify(body)));                        
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/user/create",{
                method : "POST",
                headers: {"Content-Type" : "application/json"},
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            });            
            console.log(response);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    }
```

consider api/user in main index.js file and this route is created in user.js file.
and in **Backend** I have `/create` route is as follows:-

```
router.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
    const body = JSON.parse(req.body)
    console.log('backend'+typeof(req.body));
    try{        
        const {username, email, password, firstname, lastname, country_code, phone_no,  address, city, state, country} = req.body;
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hashed_password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
        const newUser = await pool.query(
            "INSERT INTO User_ (username, email, password, firstname, lastname, country_code, phone_no,  address, city, state, country) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4,$5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11) RETURNING user_id, username"
            [username, email, hashed_password, firstname, lastname, country_code, phone_no,  address, city, state, country]
        );
        res.status(201).send(newUser.rows[0]);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("Error : ", err);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two layers to this.

First, `async` functions always return promises. If an error is thrown in an `async` function, it rejects the promise the function returned. In your route handler, you have

```
const body = JSON.parse(req.body)
```

at the top level of the `async` function. That means any errors throwing parsing the JSON will be unhandled rejections.

You would want to move that line **into** the `try`/`catch` so that it's handled, since Express doesn't do anything with the promise you return. **But**, see the next item.

Second, your error message is the classic error you get when you call `JSON.parse` on something that's *already* been parsed and is an object, because `JSON.parse` converts its argument to string, and the string you get for plain objects is `"[object Object]"` — note the `o` at position 1 (0-based).

I suspect you have middleware installed that has already parsed the JSON for you, so you don't want to do that `JSON.parse` call at all. Just use the object on `req.body`.

Comment: if i remove json.parse becuase it's already  parsed then it gives me error like : TypeError: Client was passed a null or undefined query

Comment: @SMEETKOTHARI - Do you have JSON middleware installed in the router? E.g., [`express.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json).

Comment: @SMEETKOTHARI - Then I suspect the problem isn't the JSON, the `fetch` looks right and `express.json()` isn't broken. I suggest putting a breakpoint on the line doing the destructuring (yes, you can debug Node.js server code, see `--inspect-brk` in the documentation) and see where it's failing. The error message sounds like it's coming from something after the destructuring. Adding `JSON.parse` just hid the problem by failing earlier.

Comment: I re-wote index,js as well as my route and error went away, Thnx for help @T.J.Crowder